# Unable to delete file through Finder in Desktop folder

Tags: macos, finder

I'm opening Finder and trying to delete a file or directory in Desktop folder. Hitting `cmd+backspace` or `Move to trash` doesn't work. I can hear a sound of the file being deleted but the file is still there.

When I'm trying to do this via terminal `cd ~/Desktop; rm file.txt` works like a charm.

Also I can't move a file from `Desktop` to other folder but I can copy it.

Applying read/write for my user to `Desktop` doesn't fix that.

I am able to delete files using other app - ForkLift.

Where to start?

Comment: Does this apply to all files on the Desktop or just one? Check the perms on the path to desktop as well as the file[s].

Comment: Unfortunately to all files. Permissions look OK, when I copy the file from Desktop to my home folder, the permissions are the same and I am able to delete the file in finder.

Comment: I had the same problem with the latest version of Mac OS. After restarting the laptop the problem fixed, but after a few hours it came back again, The only way O found to solve the problem was to restart the laptop.

Comment: @DimitrisKasabalis - this helped indeed, but as you've said after few hours, the problem appears again. Also when I try to unzip a file on Desktop I get error 256 whatever it means.

Comment: I'm facing the same issue. Whenever I try do delete the file via Finder, Console app reports the following error: `Sending of a 'provide' message was interrupted: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=4099 "The connection to service on pid 0 created from an endpoint was invalidated from this process." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=The connection to service on pid 0 created from an endpoint was invalidated from this process.}` HTH